# Check/Uncheck checkbox with Space/Enter in gridview in listview - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I have a `GridView` with `CheckBox` as a column and `TextBlock` as another column. Here is the `XAML` code:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                        Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>

        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Tag="{Binding}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsFormChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsUnRestricted}"
                              IsThreeState="False" 
                              UIElement.KeyUp="CheckBox_KeyUp" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn Width="auto">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Width="600"
                               Tag="{Binding}"
                               IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsUnRestricted}"
                               Text="{Binding Path=FormName}" 
                               MouseUp="TextBlock_MouseUp">
                        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FormName}"/>
                        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

When I access this `GridView` with the keyboard complete row is selected (`CheckBox` as well as `TextBlock`). Now at this point if i press space key, nothing happens. If I want to access the `CheckBox` with keyboard, I have to press tab key once more so that focus is set on checkbox and the I can check/uncheck it using space bar. What I want to do is **when the focus is on the row I want to check/uncheck checkbox with only one key press of space bar.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a binding on the currently selected item, you can handle the `PreviewKeyUp` event on your `ListView`:

```
<ListView PreviewKeyUp="OnGridKeyUp"
          SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

and then handle this in code-behind:

```
private void OnGridKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(vm.mySelectedItem != null && e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        vm.MySelectedItem.IsChecked = !vm.MySelectedItem.IsChecked;
        e.Handled = true; //this is necessary because otherwise when the checkbox cell is selected, it will apply this keyup and also apply the default behavior for the checkbox
    }
}
```

This obviously requires you to have a handle on your viewmodel from your code behind. This could be as easy as:

```
var vm = DataContext as MyViewModel;
```

this is not the most MVVM way, but hey...

Comment: hey, I have not used MVVM to that extent but PreviewKeyUp event solved my problem. Thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

I made a more MVVM friendly way to do this:

Step 1: Create this behavior

```
public class ToggleSelectOnSpace : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty toggleSelectCommand =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ToggleSelectCommand",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(ToggleSelectOnSpace));

    public ICommand ToggleSelectCommand
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(toggleSelectCommand) as ICommand; }
        set { this.SetValue(toggleSelectCommand, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyUp += PreviewKeyUp;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyUp -= PreviewKeyUp;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            if (ToggleSelectCommand != null)
            {
                ToggleSelectCommand.Execute(this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Implement a command like this in your View Model (method logic for the command)

```
    private void ToggleSelectParticipant(object selectedObjects)
    {
        var items = (System.Collections.IList)selectedObjects;
        var collection = items.Cast<MyItemType>().ToList();
        bool selection = !collection.All(x => x.IsSelected);
        foreach (var item in collection)
            item.IsSelected = selection;
    }
```

Step 3: Bind the behavior to the grid, and bind the command to the behavior

```
<DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <shared:ToggleSelectOnSpace ToggleSelectCommand="{Binding Data.ToggleSelectParticipantCommand, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
...
</DataGrid>
```

([Info on the BindingProxy source](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/))

Comment: I think this is the way to go. I would like to implement this solution, but I would prefer to be able to bind to an IsSelected property of the individual item (which already exists and is bound to the checkbox), instead of having to add a command. My problem is that I don't know how to bind a property of the item to a property of the behaviour. Could you suggest how this could be done? Thanks

Comment: You should probably [Ask a Quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and explain your problem more thoroughly.

Comment: OK, I've created a question for it, trying to explain it the best I could: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28457497/352826